# finding the index of the max value in a list of list (python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I have a list of lists and I'm trying to find the maximum value in each list. The catch is that the index of the max value cannot be the index of the list I'm referencing. So if I'm looking at list #4, I can't use index#4.  Some lists don't work, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... I'm a beginner.

```
def my_function(list_number, data):  
    data[list_number]  
    max = data[list_number][0]  
    index_max_value = 0  
    for i in (data[list_number]):  
        if i != list_number:  
            if data[list_number][i] > max:  
                max = data[list_number][i]  
                index_max_value = i  
    return index_max_value
```

Comment: Please be more clear on your objective, do you want to find the index of the element with highest value of the lists that are inside a list, or the index of the list which contains that element?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input - lists, and expected output?  It's not clear what's your goal.

Comment: @RinoSnake the index of the element with highest value of the lists that are inside a list

Answer (score 1):

In your first for loop you have to enclose iterable `(data[list_number])` in `range` and `len` functions, instead you were looping over the values of the inner list instead of the indices. here is the fixed one.

```
def my_function(list_number, data):
    data[list_number]
    max = data[list_number][0]
    index_max_value = 0
    for i in range(len(data[list_number])):
        if i != list_number:
            if data[list_number][i] > max:
                max = data[list_number][i]
                index_max_value = i
    return index_max_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the parameters of your dunction, your code seems to be looking for the index of the maximum value in a specific sublist of the list of lists.

You can leverage the max function's ability to use an indirection for the ordering of the maximum value.  If you give max() the list of indexes and values (using enumerate), and specify a lambda to use the value as order, you will get the result directly:

```
def my_function(list_number, data)
    index,_ = max(enumerate(data[list_number]),lambda e:e[1]) 
    return index
```